# Thread-holes destroyed for CPU heatsink in laptop

Tags: laptop-repair, heatsink

Recently, I was doing a cleaning session for my laptop.

After years of use, two thread-holes gived in, when screwing the CPU heatsink back in.

Unlike a *regular damaged thread-hole* its quite easy to fix, but this is a plastic casing.  More special techniques would be required to fix the problem.

*How do I fix my thread-holes in my computer-case?*

Spending $20+ on a new case, to fix an issue of two-thread holes is unreasonable.  Hopefully, this is not my only option.

Comment: Without pics, all the answers here will be fairly generic at best.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I reached my question ban after one lousy downvote. Where do I report this flaw in the algorithim?

Comment: @Travis you have asked 14 questions in the past, with 7 of them deleted and many of those down voted. No one knows the exact details of the algorithm nor can we affect it. https://superuser.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 2):

For DIY repairs on plastic threads on a budget without investing in tools or too much extra material, I think you have basically 2 options:

1. Find slightly larger screws and force them in. Plastic is soft enough that if you're careful you should be able to create new threads this way. However, finding appropriate screws can be difficult.
2. Superglue the screws in place. If you're lucky, the glue will not bond well to the metal screws and you'll still be able to remove them after the glue sets.

If you wanted to spend a bit more time and money on it you could try some brass inserts  or helicoils, as seen in this video for RC car stripped screw repair:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXt6F-J0IWs&ab_channel=Franco

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer but rather an extended comment. The main reason being the question itself is fairly generic with no specifics or even pictures. Without details, nobody can really help. Second, you are also linking to an external YouTube video. The Stack Exchange sites discourage link-only answers; answer content should be in the body of the answer itself.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Accepting if it works.

Comment: @giacombo1968 This is absolutely an answer. Further. Linking to other resources is allowable provided they are in support of, and not instead of your answer.